# GridBagConstraints.NORTH does not align panels to top when gbc.weighty = 0

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to implement a list of JPanels within a container. For some reason I am unable to align the panels to top

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH; gbc.weighty = 1;
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vanWx.png]

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH; gbc.weighty = 0;
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqek3.png]

So as you can see, the aligning to top only works when the weighty > 0.

The container is created the following way:

```
public ListSection() 
{
    setLayout( new BoxLayout( this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
    mainList = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
    mainList.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.cyan, 2 ) );

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( mainList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );
    scrollPane.setBorder( null );
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBar( new HScrollBar() );
    add( scrollPane );
}
```

Then it is called from another class:

```
mainListSection = new ListSection( );
messagesContainer.add( mainListSection );
```

And JPanels are being added:

```
public static void addToMainList( List<Message> messages )
{       
    mainListSection.getMainList().removeAll();

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    for( Message message : messages )
    {   
        if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "all" ) )
        {
            JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
            mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
        }
        else
        {
            if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "catalogue" ) && 
                ( message.type.equals( "users" ) || message.type.equals( "userpersonals" ) ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
            else if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( message.type ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
        }
    }
    mainListSection.validate();
    mainListSection.repaint();
}
```

So the problem occurs when I try to set the weighty to 0. This set the vertical align to center.

Could please anyone advise if this can be solved somehow?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

With kind help of MadProgrammer I managed to solve this problem. All I had to do is just to set weighty = 1 to the last item in the loop. So updated code looks as follows:

```
public static void addToMainList( List<Message> messages )
{       
    mainListSection.getMainList().removeAll();

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    int i = 1;
    for( Message message : messages )
    {   
        gbc.weighty = ( i != messages.size() ) ? 0 : 1;

        if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "all" ) )
        {
            JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
            mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
        }
        else
        {
            if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "catalogue" ) && 
                ( message.type.equals( "users" ) || message.type.equals( "userpersonals" ) ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
            else if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( message.type ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    mainListSection.validate();
    mainListSection.repaint();
}
```

Comment: No, that's exactly how it works.  `align` will only align components to the top of the row.  `GridBagLayout` calculates it's requirements from the middle of the container.  You will need to, somewhere, push the contents to the top of the container by making one of the rows with a `weighty` of `1` or consider using something like SwingLabs, SwingX's library `VertcialLayout` instead

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). It explains how the weighty constraint works and has working examples.

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer, your idea worked. I have set the weighty = 1 to the last row and it now looks just fine, Thanks again for idea!

Comment: *"MadProgrammer, your idea worked"*  1) Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Perhaps MadProgrammer can write that up into an answer now, or you can do the same, in order to mark this question 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. All one needs to do is to set weighty = 0 for all items except the last. The last should have weighty = 1.

```
public static void addToMainList( List<Message> messages )
{       
    mainListSection.getMainList().removeAll();

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    int i = 1;
    for( Message message : messages )
    {   
        gbc.weighty = ( i != messages.size() ) ? 0 : 1;

        if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "all" ) )
        {
            JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
            mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
        }
        else
        {
            if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( "catalogue" ) && 
                ( message.type.equals( "users" ) || message.type.equals( "userpersonals" ) ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
            else if( Toolbar.getFilterParameter().equals( message.type ) )
            {
                JPanel panel = MessageBlock.buildBlock( message );
                mainListSection.getMainList().add( panel, gbc );
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    mainListSection.validate();
    mainListSection.repaint();
}
```

Once it is done, everything starts to look fine:

[fixed alignment of the list of JPanels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBGka.png)

Many thanks to @MadProgrammer for the idea.